# a question on topology about the closure of X \ {x}

Tags: general-topology

This one seems to be an easy one but im kinda stuck
Let X be a infinite set and let T be cofinite topology. Prove that for every x on X
the closure of X\ {x}=X
i tried proving it with the definition of closure , which is the intersection of all closed ( or infinite in this case since we are on the cofinite topology) which contain X{x}
but on of these sets is X{x} since its closed. so how is gonna x be in this intersection (which i X)  ? thanks for advance

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is *not* closed, since it is infinite and distinct from $X$. Therefore, the *only* closed subset of $X$ containing $X\setminus\{x\}$ is $X$ itself.